# Angular-js show item bases on children property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to set the ng-show property of #category based on value of item.show . i.e. #category should be shown only when at-least one of the #item in that #category is shown. How can i do this? I am new to angularjs.

```
<div id='category' ng-repeat="cat in cats">
    <div  id='item' ng-show='item.show' ng-repeat="item in cat.items">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about `ng-show=cat.items.filter(function(item){return item.show}).length`?

Comment: no need to worry about it, angular will not show the inner div, if there are no items in category. do you want any thing else??

Comment: @pankajparkar true but you may not want to show the outer div because it may affect the layout itself, think margin, padding, background

Comment: @user2847643 it could possible, you could try my answer..take a look at it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div ng-show="isVisible(cat)" ng-repeat="cat in cats">
    <div ng-show="item.show" ng-repeat="item in cat.items">
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.isVisible = function (cat) {
  return cat.items.filter(function (el) {
    return el.show;
  }).length > 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply achieve this by using `ng-if` or `ng-show`

**Markup**

```
<div id='category' ng-repeat="cat in cats" ng-if="cat.items.length > 0">
    <div  id='item' ng-show='item.show' ng-repeat="item in cat.items"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i would upvote that if the question was how to show the category when at least one item is _present_, but i think the op wants to show the category if at least one _item.show is truthy_ for that category - at least that is how i understand it

Comment: @user2847643 yeah I cleared that part with op.you can look at comment